# Ubuntu 16.04 becomes extremely slow after ten hours

Tags: 16.04

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 on a Samsung desktop, 8GB RAM, 500GB HDD, NVIDIA 410M GPU, Intel CORE i5 CPU. The desktop was preinstalled with Windows 7 but I myself installed Ubuntu on it.

Every time after about 10 -- 14 hours the computer becomes extremely slow. Opening Chrome browser, Mendeley desktop, some evince PDFs, PyCharm community, each takes around ten minutes to complete. There's delay for 20 seconds in typing, and from time to time either the keyboard or some app (dark out) does not respond.

I checked System monitor. However, the RAM is far from heavily loaded. There's basically no disk usage. I don't put the screenshot here since it's highly similar to the related question shown below.

For now I have to reboot the computer every ten hours which is very inconvenient. Is there any solutions? Thanks a lot!

[Related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977430/ubuntu-16-04-extremely-slow-after-running-24-hours-and-i-cant-figure-out-why)